# Vector assignment in Verilog

Tags: verilog

It is my first attempt to use verilog. 
I have defined an 8-bit bidirectional port, a data register and a data direction register in the following way:

```
inout [7:0] pa;  //  8-bit bidirectional parallel port
reg [7:0] data_reg;
reg [7:0] data_dir_reg; // 0 --> input; 1 --> output

assign pa [7] = (data_dir_reg [7]) ? data_reg [7] : 1'bZ;
assign pa [6] = (data_dir_reg [6]) ? data_reg [6] : 1'bZ;
assign pa [5] = (data_dir_reg [5]) ? data_reg [5] : 1'bZ;
assign pa [4] = (data_dir_reg [4]) ? data_reg [4] : 1'bZ;
assign pa [3] = (data_dir_reg [3]) ? data_reg [3] : 1'bZ;
assign pa [2] = (data_dir_reg [2]) ? data_reg [2] : 1'bZ;
assign pa [1] = (data_dir_reg [1]) ? data_reg [1] : 1'bZ;
assign pa [0] = (data_dir_reg [0]) ? data_reg [0] : 1'bZ;
```

It works perfectly, however, I'm sure, there must be an easier way to accomplish the same result.

I have tried with a for cycle:

```
integer i;

for (i = 0; i < 8; i = i + 1)
  begin
    assign pa [i] = (data_dir_reg [i]) ? data_reg [i] : 1'bZ;
  end
```

as well as assigning the whole vector at once:

```
assign pa [7:0] = (data_dir_reg [7:0]) ? data_reg [7:0] : {8{1'bZ}}[7:0];
```

without any result.
Thanks for any help.

Luca

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a `generate-for` loop.

```
genvar i;
for (i = 0; i < 8; i = i + 1)
  begin
    assign pa [i] = (data_dir_reg [i]) ? data_reg [i] : 1'bZ;
  end
```

This gets unrolled into what you originally wrote.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know about generate-for loop, but after your answer and a bit more reading around I think I've got the difference between loop evaluated at compile time vs. runtime.